# Searching online from text file with python checking if the names are cities in a specific country

Tags: python

So I have a large list of geographical locations that may be cities, counties, etc, in a particular country. For example country: Turkey and list of names is: Erzurum, Eskisehir, etc.

I am wondering if I can put this list into a text file and use Python to check these names online to check what geographical entity they are instead of just Googling each term individually. How would I do that?

Comment: Sure you can. Querying the [GeoNames dataset](http://www.geonames.org/) (online or offline) might be start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). Here is an example:

**a.txt:**

```
erzurum
istanbul
turkey
chicago
united states
india
kayseri
spain
```

**Here is the code:**

```
import urllib2
import json
import time

def getEntity( entityText ):
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s' % urllib2.quote(entityText)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    jsonaddress = json.loads(response.read())

    time.sleep(0.2)

    if jsonaddress['status'] == 'OK':
        return jsonaddress['results'][0]['types'][0]
    else:
        return None

with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        entityText = line.strip()
        entity = getEntity( entityText ) 
        print entityText, entity
```

**Output:**

```
erzurum locality
istanbul locality
turkey country
chicago locality
united states country
india country
kayseri locality
spain country
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I have to search through many lists like this for my job and identify what type of entity they are, so I would like to automate many of my tasks. If I had a list of names that may or may not be brand names could I write a similar program? I don't have much experience with Python so if you could direct me to a resource that might help me with these types of tasks I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @JenniferLuévano please consider marking this as the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer if it helped you.